# I have a SQL Server database with 1500 or so tables. Is there a quick way, in one query, to ascertain the maximum value for each column in each table?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
order by table_name
```

So, I want an extra column showing the maximum value for each field in each table. I'm only really interested in dates (as I want to find out which tables are obsolete) but I can filter those out later.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that

Comment: Did you try something? What you posted is not exactly relevant, it just returns all columns. You don't even filter by the date or datetime type. Since you have the table and column name you can write a dynamic query that returns the `MAX()` of that column

Comment: There isn't a quick way, you will have to query all those tables and do the MAX on each column.

Comment: Thanks - I know I require dynamic SQL. I could paste the above (filtered by datatype) into a spreadsheet to generate the strings I want and then paste them back into SSMS - just looking for a quick way.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the queries you need:

```
SELECT concat('select ''', [TABLE_NAME], ''' as [table], ''', [COLUMN_NAME], ''' as [column], max([',[COLUMN_NAME],']) as [maxdate] from [', [TABLE_NAME], ']')
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE [TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'dbo' 
    AND [DATA_TYPE] = 'datetime'
ORDER BY [TABLE_NAME]
```

[Execute those dynamically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (stick some `union all` between them) and you're there.

Comment: Thanks, this looks brilliant but is appears that CONCAT doesn't work with 2008R2. I probably should have specified the version but this is the first question I've asked - rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

These are another solutions:

Using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SELECT @stm = (
    SELECT 
        'SELECT ''' + [TABLE_NAME] +''' AS TableName, ''' + [COLUMN_NAME] +''' AS ColumnName, MAX([' + [COLUMN_NAME] + ']) AS DataValue '+
        'FROM [' + [TABLE_NAME] + '] UNION ALL '
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
    WHERE ([TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'dbo') AND ([DATA_TYPE] = 'datetime')
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SET @stm = SUBSTRING(@stm, 1, LEN(@stm)-10)
EXEC (@stm)
```

Using cursor:

```
-- Variable declaration
DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @columnname nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)

-- Cursor declaration
DECLARE DATEVALUES CURSOR GLOBAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') AND (DATA_TYPE = 'datetime')
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME

-- Tables and columns
SET @stm = N''
OPEN DATEVALUES
FETCH NEXT FROM DATEVALUES INTO @tablename, @columnname
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) BEGIN
    IF @stm <> N'' SET @stm = @stm + N' UNION ALL '
    SET @stm = @stm + N'SELECT '''  + @tablename + ''' AS TableName, ''' + @columnname +''' AS ColumnName, MAX([' + @columnname + ']) AS MaxDate FROM ['  + @tablename + ']'
    FETCH NEXT FROM DATEVALUES INTO @tablename, @columnname
END
CLOSE DATEVALUES
DEALLOCATE DATEVALUES

-- Execution
EXEC(@stm)
```

Notes: 
Tested on SQL Server 2005 and 2012 Express Edition. In SQL Server 2005 maximum allowable table names are 256.

Comment: This works well once I've added column name. It's slow-ish because of cursor but doesn't matter as it's a one-off, although it has the benefit of running in one step rather creating the SQL in one pass and then executing afterwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

below query will give you exact answer

```
SELECT 'SELECT ''' +B.TABLE_NAME+''' AS TableName,'''+COLUMN_NAME+''' AS ColumnName,MAX('+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+') AS MaxDate FROM '+ QUOTENAME(B.TABLE_NAME)+' UNION ALL '
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] A
INNER JOIN [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] B ON A.TABLE_NAME=B.TABLE_NAME
WHERE B.[TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'dbo' 
AND [DATA_TYPE] = 'datetime' AND A.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY B.[TABLE_NAME]
```

remove last UNION ALL from the generated script.